# Using the [ ] notation on an instance from a class

Tags: c#, arrays

So I just got this question to work out: Write a console-application giving a class 'Countries'. This class must contain an array of 5 elements.Make sure to write the necessary code in this class so that the [] notation can be used on an instance from the class.

I have no idea what the last sentence means so what I did is created a class named 'Countries', and made use of ArrayLists and indexers. Yet I don't know if this is correct since it is specifically asking for an array and I have a feeling this can be done in a much simpler way (like removing the country ID and 'FirstOrDefault' function to just print every country's name).

Thank you so much for the help!

```
public class CountriesVar
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Countries
{
    private List<CountriesVar> listCountries;

    public Countries()
    {
        listCountries = new List<CountriesVar>();
        listCountries.Add(new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 1, Name = "China"});
        listCountries.Add(new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 2, Name = "Mexico" });
        listCountries.Add(new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 3, Name = "France" });
        listCountries.Add(new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 4, Name = "Spain" });
        listCountries.Add(new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 5, Name = "Italy" });

    }

    public string this[int countryId]
    {
        get
        {
            return listCountries.FirstOrDefault(lan => lan.CountryId == countryId).Name;
        }
        set
        {
            listCountries.FirstOrDefault(lan => lan.CountryId == countryId).Name = value;
        }
    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Countries countries = new Countries();

        Console.WriteLine("Name of country with ID = 1: " + countries[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Name of country with ID = 2: " + countries[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Name of country with ID = 3: " + countries[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Name of country with ID = 4: " + countries[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("Name of country with ID = 5: " + countries[5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a list have an array?

Comment: seems fine to me. maybe rename CountriesVar class to Country ? so that countries object would be a list of country objects..

Comment: OK, sure. But why make it so complicated? You could just have used a plain array and index into that in your indexer.

Comment: It may be that this is just some tutorial or some learning exercise. This can definitely be done in simpler ways, but it is good practice to learn how to extend or customize a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yeah, that wording is a little cofusing

He probably meant an indexer can be used on instances of your class, which is what you are doing

### Don't see much wrong with your code

One thing that seems odd to me is that you are defining a class and then never exposing it externally, could do that same with an int string dictionary, so might want to look into that, but gonna stick to answering question

## Using a dictionary

If they want you to return a string and to have the country id's be the thing that the indexer is working on don't see much wrong with your code, one thing that would clean things up would be to use a dictionary

```
public class Countries
{
    private Dictionary<int,CountriesVar> _dictCountries;

    public Countries()
    {
        _dictCountries = new []{
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 1, Name = "China"},
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 2, Name = "Mexico" },
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 3, Name = "France" },
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 4, Name = "Spain" },
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 5, Name = "Italy" }
        }.ToDictionary(a=>a.CountryId);

    }

    //this seems weird to me, 
    //it makes more sense to me that this would return a Coutnry
    public string this[int countryId]
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictCountries[countryId].Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictCountries[countryId].Name = value;
        }
    }

}
```

### This does act differently

This acts differently than your code, but with some tweaks will act the same, mainly just checking if something exists before trying to access it, and throwing an exception out of range **technically your code throws a null reference exception, which in my opinion is less intuitive**

```
    public string this[int countryId]
    {
        get
        {
            if(!_dictCountries.ContainsKey(countryId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("countryId");
            }
            return _dictCountries[countryId].Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!_dictCountries.ContainsKey(countryId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("countryId");
            }
            _dictCountries[countryId].Name = value;
        }
    }
```

### Can also use an array

but have to know that the country Id's align with the actual index, otherwise this method will break, since you are using an index starting at 1 for the Country Id have to do a weird thing with subtracting a number with an index and that seems wrong to me, but that might just be me.

```
public class Countries
{
    private readonly CountriesVar[] _countriesArr;

    public Countries()
    {
        _countriesArr = new []{
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 1, Name = "China"},
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 2, Name = "Mexico" },
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 3, Name = "France" },
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 4, Name = "Spain" },
                     new CountriesVar() { CountryId = 5, Name = "Italy" }
        };

    }

    //this seems weird to me, 
    //it makes more sense to me that this would return a Coutnry
    public string this[int countryId]
    {
        get
        {
            return _countriesArr[countryId-1].Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _countriesArr[countryId-1].Name = value;
        }
    }

}
```

### TLDR

You're basically doing it right, use dictionary or array in the way the code provided is doing it to get rid of your linq statement and provide a more meaningful exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly, what they were asking was to add an indexer to your class. It seems like you got a grasp of what they are talking about.